# Clion unable to find project executable when using valgrind with CLion on windows

Tags: c, windows, valgrind, clion

I'm trying to use valgrind with clion in my windows machine. I've gone through the steps of [setting up WSL](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-clion.html) and [valgrind](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/memory-profiling-with-valgrind.html) on windows. 
Although when I try to 'run with valgrind memcheck' in my 'UnixAssembler' project I get the following error:

`Error running 'UnixAssembler': File not found: /cygdrive/c/Users/natan/Desktop/UnixAssembler/cmake-build-debug/UnixAssembler.exe`

The actual exe is located in `c/Users/natan/Desktop/UnixAssembler/cmake-build-debug/UnixAssembler.exe`, so I don't know why It's looking in this `cygdrive` folder.

I'm not sure what to try from here onwards. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
- Go to **File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment**
- Remove any Toolchains other than WSL (making WSL the default will probably work as well)
- Profit